# mysql replication - how the clients knows who is the master?

Tags: mysql, replication

We want to setup a master-slave replication for mysql.
Both are on separate machines.
Imagine the scenario where the master is down, we manually change it so the slave becomes the master.
now my question is:

How do the clients of the db are aware that the master is changed? i mean if the new master has new IP doesn't it mean that switching masters will result in an error?

p.s i know this is a beginner question but after reading tutorials for replication i still cant find an answer to this.

Comment: Set up both machines with 2 IP addresses, one for MySQL to use and one for SSH etc.  When you promote the slave to the master, you stop the master listening on it's IP and bring the slave up on the master's IP.  The clients don't need to know about any IP address changes.

Comment: Your comment is not 100% clear for me, can you elaborate on this more? or maybe refer me to a tutorial? thanks

Comment: The replication chapter of [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hpmysql/chapter/ch07.pdf) has more information on this.  In particular pages 131/132.  The technique I was trying to explain is at the top of page 132.  Hope this explains it better.

Comment: @chored I don't think it's possible if the two servers are located in different continents.

Answer (score 0):

They don’t. It is up to you to make sure the client knows where to connect - this is something you can do in many ways. Let’s talk about some options.

**Hardcoded list of nodes**

One of the options will be to hardcode a list of the nodes in the application. The application, when attempting to connect to the database, will take one random (or first, or the last) node from that list and it will attempt to connect to it. If the connection attempt is not successful, the application will take another node from the list, repeating the process unless there’s no more nodes to try or some connection actually succeeded.

Once connected, the application can check what node this is. The common pattern is to use `read_only=1` for replicas and `read_only=0` for writeable nodes. If you follow that practice, the application can just check that variable and, based on its value, it can immediately tell if it hit the source node or a replica. If you do not use `read_only`, there are other ways you can check if the node is accepting writes from external clients or not (you would want to monitor binary log in general).

**Hostname**

You may have one particular hostname that points towards the source node: source_db.myenvironment.com. In that case the application just assumes that all connections towards that node will reach out a writeable node. It is then up to you to make sure that's the truth. Not going into details, as a part of the failover process, you want to always assign an IP address of the newly elected source node to that hostname in some kind of a DNS system. Be it in Consul or an external DNS, it is not that important - you just have to make such change.

**Load Balancers**

A final solution that we would discuss here (although there are hundreds of other combinations in the wild), is to use load balancers. The application connects only to one endpoint that leads to a load balancer and assumes it can execute writes just like it connected to the source node. The load balancer then monitors the status of the backend databases (for example, it monitors the value of `read_only` variable) and determines which node is writeable and which nodes are read only replicas. It then parses the queries that come from the application, perform the read/write split and sends queries to the correct nodes - writes to the source node, reads to replicas. The real logic may be more complex than this (some reads may have to be directed to the source node as well to maintain data view consistency), but this depends on the given scenario and business requirements. Sometimes the load balancer just watches the `read_only` variable, sometimes the software that executes the failover reconfigures load balancers on the fly, so it's not that important. All in all, load balancers will send the correct query to a correct node type while for the application this is pretty much transparent. One of the load balancers that works this way is ProxySQL.